# Determine the natural domain of $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt{ 5-x}}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

**(i)** Determine the natural domain of the function $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt{ 5-x}}$.

Whatever is under a radical must be non-negative. And the denominator must be non-zero.
Using these rules I got the domain to be = **[0,5).**

**(ii)** Let $f$ above have codomain ℝ. Is $f$ surjective? Justify your answer.

I know that for a function to be surjective, the function maps an element x to every element y. However I do not know how I would find this in this case?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $f(x) \geq 0$ for $x$ in  the domain of $f$. So $f$ is  not  surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the answer by René:

**(ii)** We can prove that $f$ is not surjective by producing a counterexample from the co-domain, $y \in ℝ$ such that $f(x) \neq y$ for any $x \in [0, 5)$. In this example any negative real number will do as the square root function is strictly non-negative.

Comment: thank you for this explanation @Tim C

Answer (score 2):

(i) Notice that you wanted $5-x>0$ and $\sqrt{5-x}\neq 0$. But the second statement is equivalent to $5-x>0$, since the square root function is already non-negative. And from $5-x>0$ can you conclude that $5>x$ or equivalently $x<5$. On the other hand do you have $\sqrt{x}$ in the numerator and thus you also want $x\geq 0$.Thus the natural domain is $[0,5)$.

(ii) The fact that the square root function is non-negative implies that $f$ always attains positive values and thus any negative value won't be reached by $f$.

Comment: In (i), you have forgotten the $\sqrt x$ in the numerator.

Comment: True! Will correct it

Comment: @RenéBruin that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!